# Data alignment of 64 bit Windows in terms of driver development

Tags: windows, driver, 32bit-64bit

I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff565649%28VS.85%29.aspx) on MSDN:

> On 32-bit Windows platforms, the operating system automatically fixes kernel-mode memory    alignment faults and makes them invisible to the application. It does this for the calling  process and any descendant processes. This feature, which often dramatically reduces performance, has not been implemented in 64-bit Windows. Thus, if your 32-bit driver contains misalignment bugs, you will need to fix them when porting to 64-bit Windows.

I'm somewhat frightened by this. Can anyone show me an example of the *misalignment bug*?

EDIT: I basically know the concept of alignment and its reason. I just want to figure out the diffrence between win32 and win64 in terms of "automatical fix" on alignment and the impact on my driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following structure, where `a` and `c` are 32-bit words and `b` is a byte.

```
|-----------a-----------|--b--|-----------c-----------|
|     :     :     :     :     :     :     :     |     :
```

If you allocate this structure on a 64-bit boundary, then `a` and `b` will both be aligned correctly, but `c` will not, since it crosses a 64-bit word boundary. In fact, it is impossible to layout this structure without pushing either `a` or `c` over such a boundary.

In practice, compilers will usually take a definition like this:

```
struct {
    int a;
    char b;
    int c;
};
```

and arrange it like so:

```
|-----------a-----------|--b--|     padding     |-----------c-----------|
|     :     :     :     :     :     :     :     |     :     :     :     :
```

So that none of the values crosses an alignment boundary. But in driver programming, structures often have to be packed (i.e., no padding) in order to match over-the-wire or on-disk data structure formats. That's when you can get into strife unless you unpack across word boundaries by hand.

Comment: Thanks for the graphical and literary explainations. I'm curious about the "auto fix" point. Does it mean that win32 will automatically add paddings to structure, and win64 will not? What if I #pragma pack(1) for both?

Comment: The padding is done by the compiler, regardless of architecture, not by any given version/architecture of Windows. You can suppress the compiler's default behaviour using `#pragma pack(1)` and thus force tight packing, which is often necessary for protocol coding, but that is when the trouble starts. In short, if you stick with the compiler's default behaviour, you can mostly forget about alignment issues.

Comment: @solotim Accessing misaligned data will cause a hardware exception. I guess what the "auto fix" does is to handle that kind of exceptions by breaking down the misaligned memory access into several aligned memory accesses, then returning the reconstructed value. This means that several instructions execute after the faulty one, which is what reduces performance. Again, this is just a speculation on my side, I haven't confirmed it myself.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an example to hand but the problem is quite simple to explain - you can only access 64 bit data on 64 bit boundaries.  Where data is 32 bit (or smaller) aligned you cannot access this reliably as 64 bit values because every second value will not be on a 64 bit boundary and this access will generate an exception.

WIntel machines are very tolerant of these faults but most other architectures, like ARM, throw exceptions on all alignment problems so all pointer casts are viewed with extreme suspicion.  Being careful, very careful, is the only way forward and using static analysis tools like Lint and Klocwork help a lot.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the question. By the way, is Lint available for Windows driver code?

Comment: In principle Lint is agnostic about _what_ the code does and works just as well on all platforms be they for Windows or another OS, or Intel, ARM or any other processor.  You need to be careful to make sure it is correctly configured for your platform and off you go.

Answer (score 0):

Quote [this](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.microsoft.com%2Fdownload%2Fe%2Fb%2Fa%2Feba1050f-a31d-436b-9281-92cdfeae4b45%2Fmem-mgmt.doc&ei=3dXTTNKPFIWBlAfIs6S8BQ&usg=AFQjCNGLGyWD97KDGH0XVPI5tWu9TR5fjw&sig2=tYQTJucyU78lm2aJ3HcOWQ) document in case someone has the same concern:

> If the processor tries to read or
>   write improperly aligned data, an
>   alignment fault can occur. On x86
>   hardware, the alignment faults are
>   invisible to the user. The hardware
>   fixes the fault as described in the
>   previous paragraph. On x64 hardware,
>   alignment faults are disabled by
>   default and the hardware similarly
>   fixes the fault. On the Intel Itanium
>   architecture, however, if an alignment
>   fault occurs while 64-bit kernel-mode
>   code is running, the hardware raises
>   an exception. (For user-mode code,
>   this is a default setting that an
>   individual application can change,
>   although disabling alignment faults on
>   the Itanium can severely degrade
>   performance.)